# Angularjs Retrieving param from routeProvider

Tags: angularjs, parameters, route-provider

Quick question, is it possible to get a param from a $routeProvider at the below stage?

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
        controller: 'IndexController'
    })
    .when('/students/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'views/studentRecord.html',
        controller: 'StudentsController',
        resolve: {
            students: function(getStudents) {
                  return getStudents.getAllStudents();
                },
                movies: function(getStudents,$stateParams) {
                    return getStudents.getStudentbyId($stateParams.id);
                  }
              }
            });
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

}]);

So where i have 'getStudentbyId(5)' ideally i'd want to get the :id value field. After a good amount of googling i cannot find a way. Any ideas?

Cheers

**EDIT:** when injecting $stateParams in my app.config i get '(anonymous function) angular.js:78' same as when i used $params.. eg.

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', '$stateParams', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $stateParams) {
```

Comment: Did you try just injecting and using $stateParams at that point?

Comment: i did put $stateParams in, the guy who edited it did.. which ive only just seen.. and going to give a go now

Comment: @ipaul when injecting $stateParams in my app.config i get '(anonymous function) angular.js:78' same as when i used $params

Comment: I was about to say 'I don't see $stateParams being injected,' but that makes sense.  You're configuring the routing at this point.  I think your best bet is to do the lookup for the movies data within your controller, where $stateParams can be injected.  I know it's not really an answer but the dependency injection doesn't look like it applies for 'resolve.'

Comment: People ! There is `ngRoute` and there is `uiRouter`. Just because you use a module in your app doesn't mean everyone does (or should).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's all in **[the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/%24routeProvider)**:

> Be aware that `ngRoute.$routeParams` will still refer to the previous route within these resolve functions. Use `$route.current.params`.

---

E.g.:

```
resolve: {
    studentID: function ($route) {
        return $route.current.params.id;
    }
    ...
}
```

---

See, also this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/3B75U/)**.

Comment: i added $route.current.params however I got an uncaught error with little to no description - perhaps i should have added that. could you provide an example of it working?

Comment: I just tried but can't see my webpage now. Also no errors in console

Comment: Yes, it shoyld work. Something else must be causing the issue.